# Criando view no MySQL

Tags: mysql, view

Possuo uma estrutura para `view` no banco de dados. E ao executar, o erro é que `c3.nome` não existe. Mas existe no banco de dados, acredito que seja por conta da `subquery`. Como proceder?

```
SELECT
    c1.quantidade,
    c1.valor,
    c1.data_compra,
    c2.razao_social,
    c3.nome,
    c4.usuario
FROM
    ferramental_estoque AS c1
LEFT JOIN fornecedor AS c2 ON c2.id_fornecedor = c1.id_fornecedor
WHERE
    c2.situacao IN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            fornecedor
        WHERE
            situacao = '0'
    );
LEFT JOIN ativo_externo AS c3 ON c3.id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo
LEFT JOIN usuario AS c4 ON c4.id_usuario = c1.id_usuario
```

Comment: esses LEFT JOIN não deveria vir antes do `Where`?

Comment: Além do que já foi comentado aqui `c2.situacao IN (SELECT * FROM fornecedor WHERE situacao = '0' )` sua subquery deveria retornar apenas o campo `situacao` e não todos os campos da tabela, além disso qual o sentido dessa subquery se ela retornará sempre '0'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece que é o banco de dados no decorrer da execução ele faz uma validação do seu código, pegando a lista dos atributos existentes no SELECT e buscando se existe nas suas tabelas, como o `c3.nome` é o primeiro atributo que ele encontrou que não existe ele já para, pq se existe um erro para ele executar, não precisa continuar que não ira funcionar,
corrigindo seu código deferia ficar assim.

```
SELECT
    c1.quantidade,
    c1.valor,
    c1.data_compra,
    c2.razao_social,
    c3.nome,
    c4.usuario
FROM
    ferramental_estoque AS c1
LEFT JOIN fornecedor AS c2 ON c2.id_fornecedor = c1.id_fornecedor
LEFT JOIN ativo_externo AS c3 ON c3.id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo
LEFT JOIN usuario AS c4 ON c4.id_usuario = c1.id_usuario
WHERE
    c2.situacao IN (
        SELECT
            situacao
        FROM
            fornecedor
        WHERE
            situacao = '0'
    );
```

Outro ponto a ser levando em conta é que `IN` compara um atributo com uma lista do mesmo tipo, então se deve ter uma lista de apenas um atributo e não uma vários atributos como você o fez